# How to implement AWS signed requests with amazon java library?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-advertising-api

We're currently using amazon-a2s-2007-10-29-java-library.jar to interact with the Amazon Webservices or Product Advertising API, respectively.

We don't see a way how to implement signed requests (mandatory from Aug 15) using this library, nor can we find an updated version supporting signed requests.

There does not seem to be too much discussion about this topic around, thus I suspect we're either the only ones using this lib, or otherwise just too blind to see an obvious solution for the problem.

I'd be happy for any hints on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, this library is not supported any longer and cannot be used in future.

We'll switch to the Product Advertising API Java Client Side Library.

We just found out how to generate it:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/GSG/index.html?YourDevelopmentEnvironment.html