# What is the replacement of "amazon-a2s-2007-10-29-java-library.jar"?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Does any body know what will be the replacement of this existing jar? Is there a latest jar in place of this? Since the 15th of August signed request has become mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

See: [How to implement AWS signed requests with amazon java library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205240/how-to-implement-aws-signed-requests-with-amazon-java-library)

Here is a detailed article about how to generate classes from the WSDL and sign the requests:

http://www.mularien.com/blog/2009/08/13/tutorial-amazon-soap-product-advertising-api-from-java-including-signing-of-requests-with-ws-security/

Amazon also provides some sample code to do this: http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=14